# How to color cells based on another merged cells color

Tags: excel, vba

File contains data in normal cells and merged cells and would like to color the normal cells based on highligted other merged cells, is there any VBS code for such case? here are some sample data noting that the colored cells are under "Location Group"
[image]

Didn't found any way to generate a code especially for many cells

[image]

Comment: Just to add that the cells to be colored are under B range equivalent to D range

Answer (score 0):

*Option 1:*

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub demo()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        If Range("D" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed Then
            Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

*Option 2:*

- If you have a larget table, below code will be more efficient.

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub FilterByColor()
    Dim lastRow As Long, dataRng As Range, visRng As Range
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set dataRng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    dataRng.AutoFilter
    dataRng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    Set visRng = Range("A2:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        visRng.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If
    dataRng.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

---

> Question: all highligted areas in RED will be copied (Just the area name) to another sheet with color or without  just to summariezed the problematic areas

```vb
Sub GetRedGroup()
    Dim lastRow As Long, dataRng As Range, visRng As Range
    Dim rArea As Range, arr(), c As Range, r As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim arr(1 To lastRow, 0)
    Set dataRng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    dataRng.AutoFilter
    dataRng.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
    Set visRng = Range("D2:D" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each rArea In visRng.Areas
            For Each c In rArea.Cells
                If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
                    r = r + 1
                    arr(r, 0) = c.Value
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End If
    dataRng.AutoFilter
    If r>0 Then
        Sheets.Add
        Range("A1:A" & r).Value = arr
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works perfect but is it possible to color only if it's red

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: It's perfect, thank you very much,

Comment: Last question please, is there any way to copy to another sheet just the highligted areas in RED while they are in merged cells Location Group

BELLEVILLE







HULL







JOLIETTE







LAURENTIDES

Comment: `BELLEVILLE HULL JOLIETTE LAURENTIDES` Is it a location group or 4 groups? What's another sheet? What's pasting location?

Comment: Actually this was not working as I am looking to copy just the areas highligted in RED to another sheet without merged cells (each area has D3:D10, and D11:D18) and so on, it's a big file

Comment: Option 2 is not a answer for the last question in your comment. It is for `is it possible to color only if it's red`. btw, you haven't answered my questions in my comments.

Comment: Yes location group is the header and below are the areas in merged cells, some of them will be in RED and would like to copy just the red area to another sheet called EX "Sheet 2"

Comment: `copy just the areas highligted in RED to another sheet without merged cells` eg. D3:D10 is merged cells which value is `BELLEVILLE` in source table. You want to copy it to `Sheet2` `D3:D10`. But don't keep merged cell. If it is correct, do you want to fill `D3:D10` with `BELLEVILLE`? or just keep it in cell `D3` ? Do you want to keep Red formatting?

Comment: This solution is correct but is it possible to have all these steps done by macro as well

Comment: I don't think I can revised the code coz you haven't answered my questions to clarify the requirement.

Comment: Np problem I will clarify the requirement as in the first sheet, it's a big file with merged cells as you see in the example above, all highligted areas in RED will be copied (Just the area name) to another sheet with color or without (it's not an issue) just to summariezed the problematic areas noting that the areas are in merged cells in the first sheet

Comment: I've updated the code.

Comment: It works and thank you very much, really it's highly appreciated